# How to center elements during a hover action in CSS

Tags: html, css

So I'm learning CSS and I'm still getting used to being able to correctly position all the elements. Right now, I have an HTML and CSS file that draws what basically looks like the Android robot. There's an action for the head that if you hover over it, it changes its width to 300px. The problem is that the eyes become uncentered. How can I center the eyes during the hover event?

EDIT: Bonus question; in the .eyes portion of the CSS file, I was wondering why just doing `display: flex` centers the eyes. I thought I would have to add `align_items: center` to center it across the cross axis, but just doing that first bit already centers it.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.robots {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.head,
.left_arm,
.torso,
.right_arm,
.left_leg,
.right_leg {
  background-color: #5f93e8;
}

.head {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.eyes {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.head:hover {
  width: 300px;
}

.upper_body {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
}

.left_arm,
.right_arm {
  width: 40px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.left_arm {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.right_arm {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.torso {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}

.lower_body {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  /* This is another useful property. Hmm what do you think it does?*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left_leg,
.right_leg {
  width: 40px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 0 0 100px 100px;
}

.left_leg {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.left_leg:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}

.right_leg {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.right_leg:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform: rotate(340deg);
}

.left_eye,
.right_eye {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}

.left_eye {
  /* These properties are new and you haven't encountered
 in this course. Check out CSS Tricks to see what it does! */
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40px;
}

.right_eye {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>Robot Friend</h1>
<div class="robots">
  <div class="android">
    <div class="head">
      <div class="eyes">
        <div class="left_eye"></div>
        <div class="right_eye"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="upper_body">
      <div class="left_arm"></div>
      <div class="torso"></div>
      <div class="right_arm"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="lower_body">
      <div class="left_leg"></div>
      <div class="right_leg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply try to position your eyes with margin- not with position- left:

```
.left_eye, .right_eye { 
    width: 20px; 
    height: 20px; 
    border-radius: 15px; 
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto; <-- make horizontal margin automatically
}
```

So it will still be centered even if you change element's width.

Comment: This was perfect! Thanks. By any chance, do you know the answer to the bonus question?

Comment: @Cris align_items property doesn't affects for centering your objects horizontally- because at default (flex-direction: row) it affects about your vertical alignment. as you are aligning vertical position with relative position(top: 100px), it will do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add this CSS code. (adjust the width as you need)

```
.eyes{
width:200px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.robots {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.head,
.left_arm,
.torso,
.right_arm,
.left_leg,
.right_leg {
  background-color: #5f93e8;
}

.head {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.eyes {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.head:hover {
  width: 300px;
}

.upper_body {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
}

.left_arm,
.right_arm {
  width: 40px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.left_arm {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.right_arm {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.torso {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}

.lower_body {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  /* This is another useful property. Hmm what do you think it does?*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left_leg,
.right_leg {
  width: 40px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 0 0 100px 100px;
}

.left_leg {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.left_leg:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}

.right_leg {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.right_leg:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform: rotate(340deg);
}

.left_eye,
.right_eye {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}

.left_eye {
  /* These properties are new and you haven't encountered
 in this course. Check out CSS Tricks to see what it does! */
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40px;
}

.right_eye {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 120px;
}
.eyes{
width:200px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>Robot Friend</h1>
<div class="robots">
  <div class="android">
    <div class="head">
      <div class="eyes">
        <div class="left_eye"></div>
        <div class="right_eye"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="upper_body">
      <div class="left_arm"></div>
      <div class="torso"></div>
      <div class="right_arm"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="lower_body">
      <div class="left_leg"></div>
      <div class="right_leg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The eyes are relatively positioned. Try this, at the end of your CSS:

```
.head:hover .right_eye {
  left: 170px;
}

.head:hover .left_eye {
  left: 100px;
}
```